# Qt break down by MongoDB C++ initialization

Tags: c++, mongodb, qt

I am fresh in using MongoDB c++ in Qt.

I already installed Boost, MongoDB c driver, MongoDB c++ driver and also tested DB's connection on VS2017 successfully following MongoDB tutorial(https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/).

However, a lot of problem occurred when I wanted to apply the same code on Qt.

The overall setting:

1. Win10
2. Qt Creator v4.6.0 with 
      Qt v5.10.1 MSVC2017 64-bit
      Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 15.0
      Debugger CDB x64
3. MongoDB v3.6.3
4. Boost 1.66.0 as lib64-msvc-14.1
5. Mongo c driver v1.9.3
6. Mongo cxx driver r3.2.0

The program just break down when initializing the instance as the following picture:
[Break Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMBRB.png)

The program also crashed when only using

`$`mongocxx::instance inst()

C4930 warning was produced when compiling as using

`$`mongocxx::instance inst( )

I guess there are two potential reason for my problem
Linking error
Wrong version of boost/mongocxx driver
Following is definition in .pro file

```
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/driver/c/include/libbson-1.0
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/driver/c/include/libbson-1.0
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/c/lib -lbson-1.0
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/c/lib -lbson-static-1.0


    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/driver/c/include/libmongoc-1.0
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/driver/c/include/libmongoc-1.0
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/c/lib -lmongoc-1.0
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/c/lib -lmongoc-static-1.0

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/driver/c++/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/driver/c++/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/c++/lib -lbsoncxx

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/driver/c++/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/driver/c++/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/c++/lib -lmongocxx        

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/driver/boost_1_66_0
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/driver/boost_1_66_0
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/driver/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.1 \
        -lboost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_atomic-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_bzip2-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_bzip2-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_chrono-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_container-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_container-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_context-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_context-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_coroutine-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_coroutine-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_fiber-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_fiber-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_graph-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_graph-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_locale-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_locale-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_log-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_c99-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_c99-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_c99f-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_c99f-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_c99l-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_c99l-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_tr1-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_tr1-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_tr1f-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_tr1f-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_tr1l-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_math_tr1l-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_python-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_python-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_random-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_random-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_regex-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_regex-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_serialization-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_signals-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_signals-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_stacktrace_noop-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_stacktrace_noop-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_stacktrace_windbg-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_stacktrace_windbg-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_thread-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_timer-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_timer-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_type_erasure-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_type_erasure-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_wave-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_wave-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_wserialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_wserialization-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_zlib-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -lboost_zlib-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_atomic-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_atomic-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_atomic-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_bzip2-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_bzip2-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_bzip2-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_bzip2-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_chrono-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_chrono-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_chrono-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_container-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_container-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_container-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_container-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_context-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_context-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_context-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_context-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_coroutine-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_coroutine-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_coroutine-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_coroutine-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_exception-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_exception-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_exception-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_exception-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_fiber-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_fiber-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_fiber-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_fiber-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_graph-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_graph-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_graph-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_graph-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_locale-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_locale-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_locale-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_locale-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_log_setup-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99f-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99f-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99f-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99f-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99l-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99l-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99l-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_c99l-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1f-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1f-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1f-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1f-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1l-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1l-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1l-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_math_tr1l-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_program_options-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_program_options-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_python-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_python-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_python-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_python-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_random-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_random-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_random-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_random-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_regex-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_regex-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_regex-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_regex-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_serialization-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_serialization-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_serialization-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_signals-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_signals-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_signals-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_signals-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_noop-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_noop-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_noop-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_noop-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_system-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_system-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_test_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_test_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_test_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_test_exec_monitor-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_thread-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_thread-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_thread-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_timer-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_timer-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_timer-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_timer-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_type_erasure-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_type_erasure-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_type_erasure-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_type_erasure-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wave-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wave-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wave-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wave-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wserialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wserialization-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wserialization-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_wserialization-vc141-mt-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_zlib-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_zlib-vc141-mt-s-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_zlib-vc141-mt-sgd-x64-1_66 \
        -llibboost_zlib-vc141-mt-x64-1_66
```

Is there any mistake in linking driver?

Or the version of driver I used is not correct (But it is normal using VS2017)

Does anyone encounter same problem?
TKS

Answer (score 0):

I replied to you on the mongodb mailing list, but many of the things you are doing here are incorrect. You shouldn't be linking both the static and dynamic versions of the libraries. You shouldn't be linking both the retail and debug versions of the boost libraries, etc. You should ensure that you are linking consistent versions of the boost, QT, and mongocxx/bsoncxx/libmongoc/libbson libraries w.r.t. debug/release, static/dynamic, etc.

I recommend starting from first principles and building up incrementally with things as needed. Take one of the examples from the mongocxx project, and set up a project that succesfully builds it against the driver you have built. Then add QT support.